# Purpose of modulo operator in SQL statement

Tags: sql

For a list of CustomerID's that are ranging from 1 through to 40000 what action is the WHERE clause performing when combined with the modulo operator?

Is this statment effectively saying 'Where the CustomerID (e.g. 30115) is divided by 7 and gives a remainder of 1 then set the EmailAddress to NULL'?

```
UPDATE SalesLT.Customer
SET EmailAddress = NULL
WHERE CustomerID % 7 = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, it is. (A bit odd.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is what it is doing.

Presumably, the purpose is to set about 1/7th of the emails to `NULL`.  I'm not sure what the purpose would be.  I might imagine some sort of testing.